# Bounty without one week limit, or 'informal' bounty promise?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently asked about [a specific feature for `tabular`/`array` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118816/selective-alignment-tabs-in-tabular-array) with the expectation that a package would need to be written to achieve it.

I'd like to offer a bounty as an extra incentive, but I don't want to restrict potential package writers to the one week time-limit. What would be an acceptable solution?

Can I just 'informally' promise to award a bounty in the question?

Comment: Somewhat related, I suppose: [Bounty as 'thank you'?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2971)

Comment: I suppose that is a partial answer. But more importantly, how do the moderators look upon the promise of a bounty that cannot be enforced by the system? Something like that could potentially be abused. --- Though I'm banking on their faith in this community. I guess I'm just waiting for the official go-ahead.

Comment: @mhelvens: Well, users which like to code a solution can inform you once they are finished with their solution and only post it once you placed the bounty.

Comment: So... no faith then. ;-) Just kidding. That seems sensible.

Comment: A similar incentive was offered before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3602/an-example-of-changing-kerning-of-a-font-in-lualatex

Comment: Another one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89649/pgf-tikz-qr-code-generator

Comment: Ooh... I remember that one. I think I got the idea from you, in fact. I knew I'd seen it somewhere before. I'll change mine to 300-500 points too, depending on quality. That was a good idea.